# How can I recheck every 1 second using RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Is there any method in `RxJava` to recheck if the variable is null or not, For example, Recheck every 1 second or when the value is given to the variable?

```
String x;

Completable.create(emitter -> {
    if (x != null)
        emitter.onComplete();
}).timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe();
```

Comment: This question makes little sense in the context of RxJava. This is the opposite of reactive programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, start an interval and read the value of the variable in some other operator. Note though that you'll need a `volatile` variable to be safe:

```
volatile String x;

Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.takeUntil(t -> x != null)
.ignoreElements()
.subscribe(() -> System.out.println("Done!"));

Observable.timer(3500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
.subscribe(t -> { x = "value"; });
```